# How to set a reminder in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Given a scheduler bot that asks the user to enter a date and time to book a meeting (without any connection to Google Calendar).

I want to set up a reminder as my context do remember the date and time values.

My goal is to remind the user 10 minutes before the meeting starts.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have saved the user's date/time in a database.
You could set up a background process in your application code that will run at a given interval of 10 minutes and pick up every upcoming appointment so as to send out notification to the attendees.

To be able to send notifications to the attendees via the bot, the quickstart guideline here (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#import-the-example-file-to-your-agent) shows you how to interact with an agent by using the REST API's several client libraries.

I hope this helps?